# Steep Incline Volume Algorithm for Simple JavaScript Game

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

I am writing a simple JavaScript game where you are looking for a hidden image on a page. When you click on it the image appears. On every click a sound bite plays. It is essentially Marco-polo. As you get closer to the hidden object I want the volume of the sound bite to get louder. I have this working however with a linear relation between distance and volume it is quite hard to nail down exactly where the image is, so, I want to develop a relation where there is a really steep volume incline as you get really close. Something along the lines of `y = x^5`. Doesn't have to be `x^5` but this is sort of what I have in mind.

[image]

Now, the image is placed on the page at page load randomly centred at the point `(imgX, imgY)`. The page has dimensions `(pageX, pageY)` and I click on the screen at `(clickX, clickY)`.

Now, my thinking is that there will always be a 'largest distance' `LD` on the page from the image coordinates (in theory this should be a corner on the screen). We can simply get the coordinates for the four corners and find the biggest distance, NBD.

The volume, going from 0 to 1 should have a function similar to

```
V = 1 - D
```

Where D is some relation I can't nail down right now.

To get a simple linear relation I am currently using

```
D = d / LD
```

Where

```
d = sqrt((imgX - clickX)^2 + (imgY - clickY)^2)
```

**Edit**
Just thought I would clarify my intention: 1-d/LD works however this causes a straight line increase in volume as you get closer. It's not intuitively clear but in practice as you get around 80%-100% volume it all sounds very much the same meaning that the area around the image seems to have the same volume to the human ear. I want a much more dramatic increase as you get really close. I.e., it should only get to above 80% volume when within 3-4% distance (if that makes sense)

Comment: Just use the 1- figure you have, `D` which ranges from [0..1] as the input to your attenuation function. I.e simply raise `1 - D` to the 5th power.

Comment: Sound perception is exponential/logarithmic. See decibel calculation. Which means to get equal steps in perception you need equal factors between amplitudes.

Answer (score 2):

Further to my earlier comment, here's a visualisation of what I think you need.
I've just realised that I didn't bother to re-calculate the distance from the most distant corner - I've simply used the distance from the centre of the square to the corners. This omission is the reason the red dot may be drawn to the left of the Y axis if the distance to the target exceeds the distance from the centre of the square to a corner.

Clicking on the 2nd canvas re-positions the hidden target. Moving the mouse will cause it's distance to this target to be computed. This value will then be divided by the above-mentioned max-distance-to-a-corner figure.

Finally, this value will be used as the X-coordinate of the attenuation function. The value [0..1] will be used to drive the resultant volume.
I've left a variable, `steepnessFactor` in the code for quick and easy modification of the attenuation curve. This value is simply the one to which the linear distance is raised to the power of.

```js
function allByClass(clss,parent){return (parent==undefined?document:parent).getElementsByClassName(clss)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

var steepnessFactor = 5; // inputs [0..1] will be raised to this power
var visSize = 128; // width/height of the 2 canvases

// click pos and corners of our window
var targetPoint;
var topLeft, topRight, botLeft, botRight;
// initialized to dist from center to (any) corner
var maxDist = (Math.sqrt(2) * visSize) / 2;


function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
 targetPoint = new vec2_t(visSize/2,visSize/2);
 
 topLeft = new vec2_t(0,0);
 topRight = new vec2_t(visSize,0);
 botLeft = new vec2_t(0,visSize);
 botRight = new vec2_t(visSize,visSize);
 
 var can1 = byId('graph');
 var can2 = byId('map');
 
 can1.width = visSize;
 can1.height = visSize;
 
 can2.width = visSize;
 can2.height = visSize;
 
 
 
 byId('map').addEventListener('click', onMapClicked, false);
 byId('map').addEventListener('mousemove', onMapMouseMoved, false);
 drawGraph();
 drawMap(byId('map'));
}

function drawGraph()
{
 var can = byId('graph');
 var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
 
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,can.width,can.height);
 
 // draw the axis lines
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#555555";
 ctx.moveTo(0,can.height/2);
 ctx.lineTo(can.width, can.height/2);
 ctx.moveTo(can.width/2, 0);
 ctx.lineTo(can.width/2, can.height);
 ctx.stroke();
 
 // draw the unit markers (spaced at 0.1 unit intervals)
 var numDivisions = 20;
 for (var x=0; x<can.width; x+= can.width/(numDivisions) )
 {
  ctx.moveTo(x, (can.height/2) - 4 );
  ctx.lineTo(x, (can.height/2) + 4 );
 }
 for (var y=0; y<can.height; y+= can.height/(numDivisions) )
 {
  ctx.moveTo( (can.width/2)-4, y);
  ctx.lineTo( (can.width/2)+4, y);
 }
 ctx.stroke();
 
 var scaleX = 2 / can.width;
 var scaleY = 2 / can.height;
 
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.moveTo(0,can.height);
 for (var curX=0; curX<can.width; curX++)
 {
  var scaledX = -1;
  scaledX += curX * scaleX;
 
  var curY = Math.pow( scaledX, steepnessFactor); // steepness of curve
  curY *= can.height/2;
  
  curY = can.height/2 - curY;
  
  ctx.lineTo(curX, curY);
 }
 ctx.strokeStyle = "#7e6cb5";
 ctx.stroke();
}

function vec2_t(x,y)
{
 this.x=x;
 this.y=y;
 this.equals = function(vec2){this.x = vec2.x; this.y = vec2.y;}
 this.addVec = function(vec2){this.x += vec2.x; this.y += vec2.y;}
 this.scalarMult = function(scalar){this.x *= scalar; this.y *= scalar;}
 this.vecLen = function(){return Math.sqrt( this.x*this.x + this.y*this.y );}
 this.normalize = function(){ let k = 1.0 / this.vecLen(); this.scalarMult(k); }
 this.vecSub = function(vec2){this.x-=vec2.x;this.y-=vec2.y;}
 this.toString = function(){return"<"+this.x+","+this.y+">"}
 return this;
}

function onMapClicked(evt)
{
 targetPoint.x = evt.offsetX;
 targetPoint.y = evt.offsetY;
 drawMap(this);
}

function drawMap(canvasElem)
{
 var ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
 ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasElem.width,canvasElem.height);
 var radius = 5;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(targetPoint.x, targetPoint.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
 ctx.fill();
}

function onMapMouseMoved(evt)
{
 var x = evt.offsetX, y = evt.offsetY;
 
 var curPos = new vec2_t(x, y);
 var curVec = new vec2_t();
 
 curVec.equals( curPos );
 curVec.vecSub( targetPoint );
 var curDist = curVec.vecLen();
 
 var linearDist = (1-(curDist/maxDist));
 
// console.log("CurDist / MaxDist = " + linearDist );
// console.log("CurValue = " + Math.pow(linearDist, 5) );
 
 x = linearDist;
 y = Math.pow(linearDist, steepnessFactor);   // steepness of curve
 setVolumeSVG(y * 100);
 
 drawGraph();
 var mapCan = byId('graph');
 var ctx = mapCan.getContext('2d');
 
 var scaleX = mapCan.width / 2;
 var scaleY = -mapCan.height / 2;

 var radius = 5;
 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc( x*scaleX + mapCan.width/2, 
    y*scaleY + mapCan.height/2, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
 ctx.fill(); 
 ctx.beginPath();
}

function setVolumeSVG(percent)
{
 var svg = byId('mSvg');
 var barWidth = (percent/100) * svg.width.baseVal.value;
 var barHeight = (percent/100) * svg.height.baseVal.value;
 
 var msg = "0,"+svg.height.baseVal.value + " " 
   + barWidth + "," + (svg.height.baseVal.value-barHeight) + " " 
   + barWidth + "," + svg.height.baseVal.value;
           
 allByClass('barSlider')[0].setAttribute('points', msg);
}
```

```css
#graph{ border: solid 1px black; }
#map{ border: solid 1px red; }
```

```html
<canvas width=256 height=256 id='graph'></canvas>
 <canvas width=256 height=256 id='map'></canvas><br>
  <svg id='mSvg' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 285 100" width=285 height=100>
  <g>
   <polygon class="barFrame" points="0,100 285,100 285,0"></polygon>
   <polygon class='barSlider' points="0,100 143,100 143,50"></polygon>
  </g>
  <style>
   .barFrame{ fill: #d1d3d4; }
   .barSlider{ fill: #69bd45; }
  </style>
 </svg>
```